# Proper way to update a dictionary that is constantly being updated/read?

Tags: c#, dictionary, updates

I have a function that returns a `Dictionary<uint, SomeClass>` this function is called every second updating data to my list.

Right now, used like this to update my property:

```
MyData = Api.GetData();
```

And my property as:

```
public static Dictionary<uint, SomeClass> MyData { get; private set; }
```

- Is that method fine to update my Dictionary or how should it be done?

I mean, the Dictionary is constantly being **replaced** as it is right now, right? So if I am using or updating any entry of that Dictionary say:

```
MyData[SomeValidKey].SomeProperty
```

My reference would become null or invalid? Or it would simple use a copy of it? Or this is something that would only have a chance to ever happen depending on how fast MyData is queried and the such?

**What would be an optimal way to update my Dictionary, while allowing other parts of my application to freely access and use it?**

*The dictionary is mainly read only and/or call functions of a given item in the Dictionary that is part SomeClass.*

**UPDATE:**

Since `MyData = Api.GetData();` means the list is actually replaced? If so if an entry that previously existed no longer exist but any of my functions still had it in use, it would cause exceptions? If an item that was previously used is updated I would not have the updated data as my reference is dead?

So the way I am updating my Dictionary is clearly wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're updating your `Dictionary` in a separate thread then you should use proper locking mechanism to ensure that you're reading the current value. Use `lock` for both read/write. Also there is a [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) class in .NET 4 (or above) which is designed for concurrent operations.
But if you're using your dictionary in a single thread then you shouldn't worry about locking at all. Here is an example to demonstrate what happens when you change the reference to another someClass instance:

```
private class SomeClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
...
Dictionary<uint, SomeClass> dic = new Dictionary<uint, SomeClass>
{ 
  { 1u, new SomeClass { Name = "1"}},
  { 2u, new SomeClass { Name = "2"}}
};
var sc1 = dic[1]; // sc1 refers to old instance of SomeClass
dic[1] = new SomeClass { Name = "new" }; // now we change the reference here
string oldName = sc1.Name; // oldName is still "1", because sc1 points to the old instance
```

Comment: The list is not updated in any multi-threaded operations but my main concern is directly about what happens to parts of the code that were previously reading it, since I am doing `MyData = Api.GetData()`, the list is replaced? If so say an entry that previously existed in the list, now, no longer exists but still one of my function already had an entry of it, what happens? And what happens if that entry still exists but was updated, I mean its not a reference of the new entry right? since it was completely replaced? Thinking about those makes me thing that the way I update my list is wrong!

Comment: @Guapo it depends. Since your code is not multithreaded then if you get the value before updating the Dictionary you'll have a reference to 'SomeClass' object and you shouldn't worry about it at all. But keep in mind that if you then change s.t in 'SomeClass', then it will be changed, since it is a reference type.

Comment: I see, but say the items being in the list are also a way to tell "this item is valid" and not being in the list "this item is invalid" I would be technically trying to access an invalid item so perhaps it would be better if instead of replacing the list I remove/add items to it?

Comment: If you replace an item you still have a reference to the old instance of 'SomeClass' in your function until you get the new reference to your new 'SomeClass' instance.

Comment: So I would have to further create a function to invalidate that object in order to prevent it from being used else where? In case I don't want it accessible or anything if not present in the list.

Comment: It's totally up to your business logic.

Comment: I'll update my answer to clearly show the concepts in a piece of code.

Comment: One last question, say I do MyData.Values.ToList() does the resulting list still a reference and is there any benefit or scenario this would be useful?? Any generic example of this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the resulting list regains reference to old objects and if you replace one of the objects with a new one, that item in your list will still point to old object.

Comment: Note that answer does not address code in the question at all - treating the dictionary as immutable object (and replace reference) as shown in original post is safe for single and multi-threaded code, the only issue with multi-threaded code could be staleness of the value...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is different to your example. Your example states you are replacing your dictionary when you call your API. Your question corresponds to updating.

If you were to update your dictionary, then you can either assign the return of your Api call to a temporary dictionary, then transfer/add/delete values in MyData or pass MyData to your Api function and handle that functionality there. This would keep your references in tact if accessed from other parts of your application.

If this isn't possible, then you cannot guarantee that there aren't to be errors from other parts of your code when you replace your MyData object with your Api call. The easiest solution here would that you do not cache your MyData entry value but instead cache its key. Other parts of your application can then check if their cached key is valid and take appropriate action.